# Android Textview background color resource

Tags: android, background, textview, selector

I have a `listView`. custom_listitem1.xml is used for the items display in the list. Now i want to set `Selector` based color resource(list_selector_color.xml) for the background of the item.

**custom_listitem1.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/list_selector_color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>
```

**list_selector_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

but it is giving following errors.....

```
06-06 18:38:19.422: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.newView(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:79)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.newView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:96)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:182)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1108)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:920)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:329)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     ... 52 more
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/list_selector_color.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070000
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1693)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:335)
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603):     ... 56 more
06-06 18:38:19.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18603): Caused by: org.xmlpul
```

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: where you have put your list_selector_color.xml file in your project.

Comment: I recoomend putting "list_selector_color.xml" in res/drawable folder. If it doesnt exist, create "drawable" folder under res directory first.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use color selector as a background. You may use drawable selector instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item><!-- pressed -->

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item><!-- focused -->

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item><!-- default -->

</selector>
```

You will have to put it in `drawable/` folder instead of `color/` and access as

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector_color"
```

Comment: Dude! I never thought of creating the shape within the <item> tag! You're a genius. I always hated the fact I can't use the android:color directly inside <item> tag itself, thus I would always create separate files for each <shape>!

Answer (score 7):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background"//color 1
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvheader"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EC7703"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="  Edit Items" />
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvsl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/translucent_red"//color 2
    />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background">
         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsl"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvname"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/background"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/row">
    <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:prompt="@string/medicine_info"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/slcolon"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvqty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/background"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtqty"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvuom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/background"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtuom"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/background"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:stretchColumns="*" >
   <TableRow>
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/Btnok"
       android:text="Edit" />
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/Btndelete"
       android:text="Delete" />
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/Btncancel"
       android:text="Cancel" />
   </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#F7BE57">//collor change by using color code
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maincolon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="                    " />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprovider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Provider : Softworks"
         />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need different colors at different state(e.g pressed, focus) of same view. Let default color is black, on press it will be yellow, if it is focused, it will be red. How it is possible in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store the list_selector_color.xml ?
if it's in res/color try to relocate it to res/drawable
and call like `android:background="@drawable/list_selector_color"`

Comment: This doesn't work - the list_selector_color.xml file causes a runtime error because each <item> needs to have a the android:drawable attribute set if it's being pulled from the drawable folders.  Having android:color set isn't enough.  :\

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `color.xml` into ...`\res\values\color.xml` project directory.
sample `color.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="background">#1474c0</color>
<color name="row">#ff0000</color>
<color name="translucent_red">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

then how to use color?please see this example and added line by +++++++
sample main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
+++++++android:background="@color/translucent_red">
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Notes!"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to show different color at different state(e.g pressed, focus) for TextView. How it is possible in your way?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible if you define each `textview` into each `LinearLayout` then it works.

Comment: can you some code sample how we can set different colors at different state(e.g pressed, focus) for LinearLayout?

Answer (score -1):

Now i understand that what you mean.ok see the following example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topField" android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/topField_design" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/digitsText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:maxLines="1" android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="28sp" android:freezesText="true" android:background="#F7BE57"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:contentDescription="description"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:editable="true" android:cursorVisible="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now "topField_design.xml" is a drowable resource xml file that contain drowable image resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dial_textfield_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dial_textfield_selected" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dial_textfield_normal" />//btn_dial_textfield_normal is a .png image resource into drowable folder "btn_dial_textfield_normal.png"
</selector>
```